# Post request not sent throws "405 method not allowed"

Tags: django, apache, http-status-code-405

I am not able to submit a post request as i get back the respose saying "405 method not allowed".I checked my ssl.conf and .htaccess files no such limit has been made.What could be the reason? how to resolve it?

Comment: why and how you are using .htacess with django?

Comment: i'm running django behind apache sever

Comment: Can you post your django view and form tag with attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are using class-based views. If so then you need to define post method in your view or use mixin which does it (django.views.generic.edit.ProcessFormView for example). If you want to fully understand why this is necessary then look at dispatch method of django.views.generic.base.View

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L56